# RxJava call Toast in .subscribe() method

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I have this mrthod. I was told that using toast in subscribe method is wrong.

```
MyApplication.me().getDatabase().productDao().getAllByCategoryCode(categoryCode)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(categories -> {
                    productsAdapter = new ProductsAdapter(categories);
                    productsAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(item -> {
                        BascetService.me().saveProducts(item);
                        Toast.makeText(ProductsFragment.this.getActivity(), "Add", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    });
                    productsList.setAdapter(productsAdapter);
                });
```

Can I use `Toast` in this place? If I can not how can I change this code?

Comment: read this. it may help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42654986/5202007

Comment: Why would it be wrong unless you are doing it from a background thread? or are you looking for doOnSubScribe?

Comment: You are observing on main thread, so yes you can.

Comment: one user said that here I'm doing wrong and did not say why. I did not hesitate a lot and decided to find out what might be wrong here

Answer (score 0):

You're observing on the main thread, so you're allowed to show a toast, but it depends on you split jobs